# Can't pause slideshow with cleartimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, slideshow, banner, cleartimeout

So I'm learning javascript and I'm currently working on an assignment where I need to create a banner that cycles through multiple images with a pause button, problem is, I can't seem to pause it with clearTimeout()

````
var images = [];
var timer;

images[0] = 'destaque-home.png';
images[1] = 'destaque-home-1.png';
images[2] = 'destaque-home-2.png';



function changeImg(){
    
    document.MoveBanner.src = images[i];
        
    if(i < images.length - 1){
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    var timer = setTimeout("changeImg()", 1000);
    console.log(timer);
}       

function LeftArrow() {
        i--;
    if (i < 0){
        i=2;
    }
    document.MoveBanner.src = images[i];
}

function RightArrow() {
    document.MoveBanner.src = images[i];
        i++;
    if (i > 2){
        i=0;
    }
}

function PauseBut() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

window.onload = changeImg;```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var timer = setTimeout("changeImg()", 1000);`

Because you used `var`, the variable you create is not the same as the global `var timer` variable declared at the top of the code.  That means that the PauseBut function is trying to clearTimeout with the wrong `timer`.

To instead use the globally scoped `timer`:

`timer = setTimeout("changeImg()", 1000);`

Comment: Yeah, apparently that was it. I thought I always had to use var when declaring a value. Thanks a lot